# Internet Explorer error help on jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a jQuery image gallery script that works fine on all browsers except in Internet Explorer. I get the error

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

I looked this up, and it seems this is normally caused by variables and code elements with the same name. I don't see any overlap in my code though. The error says it is located in this code:

```
// Append new picture
jQuery('<img />')
    .attr('src', p)
    .attr('id', pid)
    .css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        opacity: 0.0
    })
    .bind('click.gallery', function (event) {
        options.onClick.apply(this, [event, pict.get()]);
    })
    .appendTo('#' + id)
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, {
        queue: false,
        duration: duration,
        easing: 'linear'
    })
    .load(function () {
        pict.data('loaded', true);
    });
```

Comment: What exact object does not support property?

Comment: options.onClick.apply(this, [event, pict.get()]); - I guess options doesn't have an onClick event handler yet, and therefore since it's a null reference instead of a function reference, it doesn't have apply. Try $(options).click() instead to simulate the event.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing?

Comment: IE is saying the error occurs on the first line of this code. @Spudley I'm checking IE8 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out there was a double script being included in the page. (Site was not originally designed by me) This was apparently causing the problem. I removed the script and all is running fine.